# Simulation packages or theory to work with gravitational collapse of massive molecular clouds?

Tags: star-formation, n-body-simulations, newtonian-gravity

So, I am getting interested in gravitational collapse of large molecular clouds that fragment and collapse into multiple stars. Are there well-known popular academic simulation packages that simulate these, for research purposes? Or are there papers or references I can use to write my own?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds very ambitious! I think your way in to this topic might be to have a look at the works of two authors - [Matthew Bate](http://www.astro.ex.ac.uk/people/mbate/) and [Mark Krumholz](https://sites.google.com/a/ucsc.edu/krumholz/).

The reason I suggest these two names is that they are representative of the two basic approaches to simulating the collapse of molecular clouds (which has little to do with n-body simulations). These approaches are known as [Smoothed-Particle Hydrodynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothed-particle_hydrodynamics) (SPH) and [Adaptive Mesh Refinement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_mesh_refinement) (AMR).

Crudely put, SPH treats the fluid as discrete particles whose properties are smoothed over the size of a kernel - the resolution is controlled by the number of particles in the simulation and the smoothing length. AMR is a more "traditional" grid-based approach where the size of the grid is varied adaptively with time and space to get the requisite resolution.

A quick google reveals a number of public codes -e.g. for SPH there is [SPHYSICS](https://wiki.manchester.ac.uk/sphysics/index.php/SPHYSICS_Home_Page) or [GRLAB](http://www.ase.uc.edu/~liugr/SPH.html); for AMR there is [ENZO](http://iopscience.iop.org/0067-0049/211/2/19) or [PARAMESH](http://www.physics.drexel.edu/~olson/paramesh-doc/Users_manual/amr.html).

One of the main activities in model simulations these days is trying to incorporate "feedback" into star formation. i.e. the winds and radiation from newly born high-mass stars and the outflows from protostars. Such things do not form part of standard codes.